# Conditional Gathering of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Just need a little help with the `GatherBy` / `SplitBy` function(s).

I have a list of random numbers here:

```
{8, 4, 2, 1, 9, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 11, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3, \
1, 2, 7, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 4, 15, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 7, \
2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 4, 11, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 2, 4, 9, 1, 2, 4,
  8}
```

How can I write a function with a look-ahead? I want to gather the numbers so it splits whenever it the next number is larger than the current one? (spaced for clarity):

```
{{8, 4, 2, 1},
{9, 4, 2, 1},
{5, 2, 1},
{3, 1},
{2},
{11, 4, 2, 1},
...}
```

Tried and failed:

```
SplitBy[%, Greater]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need [`Split`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Split.html):

```
Split[list, Greater]
```

[`SplitBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SplitBy.html) doesn't work here because the specified function is applied to *each element separately* before doing a normal `Split`.  What you want is a pair-wise comparison with a custom comparator, which is what `Split` does.

---

Looking at this again you may want `GreaterEqual` to group identical elements in the same list:

```
Split[{2, 1, 1, 7, 5, 5, 5, 6, 0}, GreaterEqual]
```

> ```
> {{2, 1, 1}, {7, 5, 5, 5}, {6, 0}}
> ```

For fun I tried to do this operation without `Split`.  Since I was having fun I used `Do` rather than `Module` to localize symbols `i` and `x`.

```
split = Last @ Reap @ Do[If[n > x, i++]; Sow[x = n, i], {i, 1}, {x, 1}, {n, #}] &;

split @ {2, 1, 1, 7, 5, 5, 5, 6, 0}
```

> ```
> {{2, 1, 1}, {7, 5, 5, 5}, {6, 0}}
> ```

Answer (score 11):

Use `Split[list,Greater]` instead of `SplitBy[list,Greater]`.

Comment: It took me a while to answer this because my first attempts  were all too short. Why do answers have to be at least 30 characters long?

Comment: To prevent spam, I guess. Also, chances are that such answers will not be very informative. The model was first designed for StackOverflow, and many popular languages are more verbose than Mathematica.