# Split a list of pairs at points with decreasing first element

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list in which the first index is mostly increasing, but dips sometimes.

I need to split this list in two or more lists in this way: when the first element of a pair is smaller than the preceding first element, I need to split the list and create new separate lists.

This is an explanatory example:

```
list = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}, {4, 40}, {5,50},
        {2, 20}, {3, 30}, {4, 40}, {5, 50}, {1, 10}, {2, 20}, {4, 40}};

newlist1 = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}, {4, 40}, {5, 50}};
newlist2 = {{2, 20} {3, 30} {4, 40} {5, 50}};
newlist3 = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {4, 40}};
```

Comment: I formatted and rephrased your question and the title slightly to make it more accessible.

Answer (score 11):

It's very easy :

```
 list = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}, {4, 40}, {5, 50}, {2, 20}, {3, 
        30}, {4, 40} , {5, 50}, {1, 10}, {2, 20}, {4, 40}};

 Split[list, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &]
```

> {
>      {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}, {4, 40}, {5, 50}},
>       {{2, 20}, {3, 30}, {4,40}, {5, 50}},
>     {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {4, 40}}
>     }

Comment: @Mary note `Split` can be highly abused and can do amazing things, if you can figure out what the splitting function needs to be. [Here's everything](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Split) that references `Split` on this site. It is worthwhile looking through.

Comment: I think this should be `<=` rather than `<` based on my reading of the question.

Comment: @rcollyer A better search might be [restricted to code.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=code%3ASplit)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I did not know you could do that; show off. :)

Comment: @andre Thanks very easy solution!

Comment: @rcollyer You're right!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a function that is several times faster than `Split`:

```
runs[a_List] := Inner[a[[# ;; #2]] &, Prepend[# + 1, 1], Append[#, -1], List] & @
  SparseArray[UnitStep @ Differences @ a[[All, 1]], Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

Test:

```
list = {{1, 10}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}, {4, 40}, {5, 50}, {2, 20}, {3, 30}, {4, 40},
        {5, 50}, {1, 10}, {2, 20}, {4, 40}};

runs[list] // Column
```

> ```
> {{1,10},{2,20},{3,30},{4,40},{5,50}}
> {{2,20},{3,30},{4,40},{5,50}}
> {{1,10},{2,20},{4,40}}
> ```

```
big = Join @@ ConstantArray[list, 100000];

runs[big]                        // Timing // First
Split[big, #1[[1]] <= #2[[1]] &] // Timing // First
```

> 0.234
>
> 0.78

---

Related:
- [Conditional Gathering of lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3412/conditional-gathering-of-lists)
- [Find continuous sequences inside a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23607/find-continuous-sequences-inside-a-list/23623#23623)

Comment: not something for the casual debugger, though :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard very smart solution!

Comment: @Mary Thanks; glad you like it.  The `SparseArray` thing is fairly esoteric (and AFAIK undocumented).  There are other examples of the use of `SparseArray` Properties in the second linked post at the bottom of this answer.