# Partition on sublists beginning with a certain marker elements

Tags: list-manipulation, gathering

Say I have the list

```
{{a}, {0, 2, 5}, {5, 4, 1}, {a}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 4, 2}, 
 {3, 3, 0}, {a}, {3, 2, 0}, {1, 4, 1}}
```

I would like to make sublists of everything beginning with the `{a}` element till the next `{a}` or the and of the list.

Either

```
{{{0, 2, 5}, {5, 4, 1}},
 {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 4, 2}, {3, 3, 0}},
 {{3, 2, 0}, {1, 4, 1}}}
```

or

```
{{{a},{0, 2, 5}, {5, 4, 1}},
 {{a},{1, 1, 0}, {1, 4, 2}, {3, 3, 0}},
 {{a},{3, 2, 0}, {1, 4, 1}}}
```

would be acceptable.  I'm sure there is a duplicate, but I can't find the easiest way to do this  (that isn't a clunky `While` loop with an `AppendTo`)

Comment: Related: [(2952)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2952/121), [(3412)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3412/121), [(23607)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/121), [(47296)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47296/121), [(77796)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77796/121)

Comment: @Kuba - in the actual job I'm doing, I'm trying to get molecule geometries from a large text file where they are always preceded by a line that is like "----------------------".  I can probably do it better with some combination of grep and awk, but I can never figure out awk.

Comment: @JasonB Ok, I've adjusted the wording to take that into account :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
Split[list, (#2 =!= {a}) &]
```

> ```
> {
>  {{a}, {0, 2, 5}, {5, 4, 1}},
>  {{a}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 4, 2}, {3, 3, 0}}, 
>  {{a}, {3, 2, 0}, {1, 4, 1}}
> }
> ```

If you add `Map@Rest` you will get the first form.

Alternatively, for `V10.2+` users:

```
SequenceCases[list, {{a}, Except[{a}] ...}]
```

or

```
SequenceCases[list, {{a}, Longest[___]}]
```

Comment: This is great.  Can you tell me what the practical difference is between `!=` and `=!=` are?  Either one seems to give the same result for your code.   Perhaps when only comparing two things there is no difference? Or it's similar to the difference between `SameQ` and `Equal`

Comment: Answered my question there, via [this blog post](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=3217):  "If you are not sure if someone gives a variable or a value you can use =!= to force a true or false"

Comment: @JasonB :) so you know. But that's not so easy, maybe you want 1 to be 1. then == gives true and === false.

Answer (score 5):

```
Rest /@ Internal`PartitionRagged[list, 
   Flatten@Differences@Position[Append[list, {a}], {a}]] // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, I was trying something like `Span@Partition@Position.....` but I like `PartitionRagged` better.  Where are all these undocumented functions listed?  Are they in a staging area for the next version?  :-)

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/805/what-are-some-useful-undocumented-mathematica-functions

Answer (score 5):

```
SplitBy[l, FreeQ[{##}, a] &] /. {{a}} :> Sequence[]
```

Or

```
Level[Nest[
   MapAt[TakeDrop[#, First@FirstPosition[#, {a}]] &, 
     Level[#, {-3}], -1] &, {l}, 
   Length[Position[l, {a}]]], {-3}] //. {a} | {} -> Sequence[]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Join @@@ Partition[SplitBy[list, MemberQ[{{a}}, #] &], 2]
```

> {{{a}, {0, 2, 5}, {5, 4, 1}}, {{a}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 4, 2}, {3, 3, 
>      0}}, {{a}, {3, 2, 0}, {1, 4, 1}}}