# How to transform {"Mon", 1, 2, 3, 10, 100, "Tue", 7, 11} to {{"Mon",1,2,3,10,100}, {"Tue",7, 11}}

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

Consider the following code snippet:

```
GroupBy[{"Mon", 1, 2, 3, 10, 100, "Tue", 7, 11}, MemberQ[{"Mon", "Tue"}, #] &]
```

With output:

```
<|True -> {"Mon", "Tue"}, False -> {1, 2, 3, 10, 100, 7, 11}|>
```

I expected however the following output:

```
<|"Mon" -> {1,2,3,10,100}, "Tue" -> {7, 11}|>
```

With the purpose of finally transforming this to

```
{{"Mon",1,2,3,10,100}, {"Tue",7, 11}}.
```

My question is really about how to transform lists like

```
{"Mon", 1, 2, 3, 10, 100, "Tue", 7, 11} to

{{"Mon",1,2,3,10,100}, {"Tue",7, 11}}.
```

and

```
{"Mon", 1, "Tue", 7, 11, "Sat",6 } to

{{"Mon",1}, {"Tue",7, 11}, {"Sat",6}}.
```

and so on ?

Comment: I think it is a duplicate of: [Partition a list based on specific elements?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104153/5478), you only need to change the test to `Not @ StringQ[#2] &`. Do you agree?

Comment: If anyone disagrees with closing, there is the reopen button above.

Comment: My question is different @Kuba although it looks the same. Applying the answers in noted question did not help me.

Comment: Here is a counterargument: `Split[{"Mon", 1, "Tue", 7, 11, "Sat", 6}, Not@StringQ[#2] &]` which gives your desired result and uses the same method.

Comment: I see your interest, you answered the question.

Comment: Split[{"Mon", 1, "Tue", 7, "A", 11, "Sat", 6}, Not@StringQ[#2] &] does not work.

Comment: It does but you need a good testing function, here probably `Not@MemberQ[{"Mon", "Tue", "Sat"}, #2] &`. But your initial test does not include `"Sat"` either so don't be picky.

Comment: OK. Will have a further look

Comment: Works brilliantly.

Comment: I'm glad it does :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Join @@@ Partition[
  SplitBy[{"Mon", 1, 2, 3, 10, 100, "Tue", 7, 11}, MemberQ[{"Mon", "Tue"}, #] &],2]
```

Comment: Generalize: `Join @@@ Partition[SplitBy[list, Head@# == String &], 2]`

Comment: @corey979 `Head@# == String &` --> `StringQ`.

Comment: This one looks beautiful indeed @corey979

Answer (score 2):

Might be done this way, using Internal`PartitionRagged to make arbitrary partitions

```
ls = {"Mon", 1, 2, 3, 10, 100, "Tue", 7, 11}

diff = Differences@Flatten@Join[Position[Head /@ ls, String], {{Length@ls + 1}}]
Internal`PartitionRagged[ls, diff]
```

> {{"Mon", 1, 2, 3, 10, 100}, {"Tue", 7, 11}}