# Rule-based creation of sub-lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
lis = {a,b,c,d,a,e,f,a,g,h,i,a,k}
```

and would like to arrive at the following:

```
res = {{b,c,d},{e,f},{g,h,i},{k}}
```

Doubtless already asked and answered, but even just a pointer to the previous answer would be much appreciated!

Comment: That is the answer, right? [Partition on sublists beginning with a certain marker elements](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104153/5478)

Comment: What rule determines which subsets are to be created?

Comment: Just making sublists consisting of whatever elements follow an instance of "a" before the next "a" shows up.  The proposed solutions all work. Thank you all for your prompt help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works - perhaps there is a simpler version?

```
Select[SplitBy[lis, # === a &], # =!= {a} &]
```

Answer (score 10):

```
SequenceCases[{a, b, c, d, a, e, f, a, g, h, i, a, k}, {Except[a] ..}]
```

> {{b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i}, {k}}

Answer (score 4):

Or with `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[SplitBy[lis, # === a &], {a}]
```

> {{b, c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h, i}, {k}}

---

Extended version:

```
DeleteCases[SplitBy[lis, # === a &], s_ /; s == {a}]
```