# List partition by delimiter

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to gather elements of a list separated by a delimiter `":"`

```
lis = {"az", "2","b",":","7","b",":","7","c"}
```

to make:

```
lis2 = {{az, 2,b},{7,b},{7,c}}
```

Thanks in advance for any direction...

Comment: Much more elegant than my solution, thank you!

Comment: at least closely related: [Partition on sublists beginning with a certain marker elements](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104153/5478)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This

```
is = {"az", "2", "b", ":", "7", "b", ":", "7", "c"};
DeleteCases[SplitBy[lis, # == ":" &], {":"}]
```

returns {{"az", "2", "b"}, {"7", "b"}, {"7", "c"}}

Comment: `SameQ[]` (`===`) is more suitable here than `Equal[]`.

Comment: `DeleteCases[SplitBy[lis, # === ":" &], {":"..}]` would be better since this will also work if multiple separators occur in sequence.

Answer (score 9):

In 10th and later versions you can also use `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[lis, {a : Except[":"] ..} :> {a}]
```

> {{"az", "2", "b"}, {"7", "b"}, {"7", "c"}}

Also:

```
Split[#, # =!= ":" &] /.  ":" | {":"} -> (## &[]) & @ lis
```

> {{"az", "2", "b"}, {"7", "b"}, {"7", "c"}}

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of page visitors, this functionality was made available in 2018 through `SequenceSplit`.

[image]

---

```
lis = {"az", "2", "b", ":", "7", "b", ":", "7", "c"};
SequenceSplit[lis, {":"}]
```

> {{"az", "2", "b"}, {"7", "b"}, {"7", "c"}}