# How to split sublists into sub-sublists without merging the sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

This is an extension of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176040/how-to-split-list-into-segments-based-on-first-element-of-sublist-and-remove-in).

I have `xyPairsAll`, which is a matrix holding sublists. It looks like

```
{...
{{1., 1812.}, {2., 10076.}, {3., 4764}, {1., 3475.}, {2., 3572.}, {3., 3985.}}, 
{{1., 6839.}, {2., 3849.}, {3., 2746}, {1., 3578.}, {2., 5629.}, {3., 3849.}},  
{{1., 6839.}, {2., 3849.}, {3., 2746}, {1., 10092.}, {2., 1638.}, {3., 3728.}}
...}
```

I want to split each sublist into 1., 2., 3. sub-sublists based on the first {x, y} pair of each sublist. I don't want to merge any of the sublists; the resulting matrix will gain one more level. It should look like

```
{...
{{{1., 1812.}, {2., 10076.}, {3., 4764}},   
 {{1., 3475.}, {2., 3572.}, {3., 3985.}}}, 
{{{1., 6839.}, {2., 3849.}, {3., 2746}},    
 {{1., 3578.}, {2., 5629.}, {3., 3849.}}}, 
{{{1., 6839.}, {2., 3849.}, {3., 2746}},    
 {{1., 10092.}, {2., 1638.}, {3., 3728.}}}
...}
```

I can do the split operation on the first sublist with

`Split[xyPairsAll[[1]], (First[#2] > First[#1]) &]`

How can I repeat the same split operation on all the other sublists too, without merging them?

Comment: `Split[#, ((First[#2] > First[#1])&)]& /@ xyPairsAll`?

Comment: Ahhhhh. It works. I had tried that with xyPairsAll[#]] instead of just #. Not sure why, because that doesn't even make sense. Thanks, @eyorble

Answer (score 2):

```
Partition[#, 3] & /@ xyPairsAll
```

Answer (score 1):

The structural modification seems to be the same in all rows, so I think `ArrayReshape` will work:

```
L = {
     {{1., 1812.}, {2., 10076.}, {3., 4764}, {1., 3475.}, {2., 3572.}, {3., 3985.}}, 
     {{1., 6839.}, {2., 3849.}, {3., 2746}, {1., 3578.}, {2., 5629.}, {3., 3849.}},  
     {{1., 6839.}, {2., 3849.}, {3., 2746}, {1., 10092.}, {2., 1638.}, {3., 3728.}}
    };

With[{dim = Dimensions[L], max = Round[Max[L[[1, All, 1]]]]},
 ArrayReshape[L, ReplacePart[dim, 2 -> Sequence[dim[[2]]/max, max]]]]
```

> ```
> {
>  {{{1., 1812.}, {2., 10076.}, {3., 4764}}, {{1., 3475.}, {2., 3572.}, {3., 3985.}}},
>  {{{1., 6839.}, {2., 3849.}, {3., 2746}}, {{1., 3578.}, {2., 5629.}, {3., 3849.}}},
>  {{{1., 6839.}, {2., 3849.}, {3., 2746}}, {{1., 10092.}, {2., 1638.}, {3., 3728.}}}
> }
> ```