# Split list based on a threshold

Tags: list-manipulation

**Problem**

I have to split a list into multiple lists whenever any element of the list is above a certain threshold. The last element of my list is always `zero` or less than threshold.

```
exlist = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 11, 14, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 10, 0}; (*example list*)

thres = 10; (*threshold value used*)
```

**Expected Result**

I am expecting a result for the above as:

```
res = {{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 12}, {1, 1, 11}, {14}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 10, 0}}
```

**My approach using `SplitBy` function**

I am using `SplitBy` function without getting expected result.

```
SplitBy[exlist, #>threshold&]
(* res = {{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1}, {12}, {1, 1}, {11, 14}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 10, 0}}*)
```

It seems like I am not using the `SplitBy` or `Split` correctly.

**Other approach**

I have used a crude way of tackling this problem.

```
grlist = Select[exlist, # > thres &] (*generate list of elements which exceed threshold*)
(* {12, 11, 14} *)

poslist = Position[exlist, #]&/@grlist (*find position of elements exceeding threshold*)
(* {{{8}}, {{11}}, {{12}}} *)

reposlist = poslist[[#, 1, 1]]&/@Range[Length[poslist]] (*reformat poslist*)
(* {8, 11, 12} *)

AppendTo[reposlist, Length[exlist]] (*join length of exlist as last element of reposlist*)
(*{8, 11, 12, 20}*)

For[k = 1; i = 1; res = {};,
i < Length[reposlist] + 1,
AppendTo[res, exlist[[k ;; reposlist[[i]]]]];
k = reposlist[[i]] + 1;
i = i + 1;
];

(* {{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 12}, {1, 1, 11}, {14}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 10, 0}} *)
```

**Question**

Is there any elegant solution for the problem using either `Split`/`Splitby` function or any other approach?

Comment: Based on [104156](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104156/5478) `Split[exlist, #1 <= thres & ](* ! #1 > thres *)`

Comment: Thanks @Kuba This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 11, 14, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 10, 0};

n = 10;
```

Using `Position` and `TakeList`

```
p = Position[list, x_ /; x > n]
```

{{8}, {11}, {12}}

```
TakeList[list, Flatten[{First @ p, Differences @ p, All}]]
```

{{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 12}, {1, 1, 11}, {14}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 10,
0}}

Answer (score 2):

```
exlist = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 11, 14, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 10,
    0};
thres = 10;    
SequenceReplace[exlist, {a___ /; Max@a <= thres, b_} -> {a, b}]
```

or

```
SequenceSplit[exlist, {a___ /; Max@a <= thres, b_} :> {a, b}]
```

or

```
SequenceSplit[exlist, k : {a___ /; Max@a <= thres, b_} :> k]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 12}, {1, 1, 11}, {14}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 10,
> 0}}

Comment: +1 - I tried, but couldn't find a solution with one of the `Sequence`-functions

Comment: +1 Or `SequenceCases`: Same result. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
l = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 11, 14, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 10, 0};
```

---

Another way is as follows:

```
p = Flatten@Append[Flatten@Position[#, Last@#]]@Position[#, x_ /; x > 10] & @ l;

f = Splice@Part[l, #] & /@ {Span[##]} &;

f @@@ Prepend[{1, First@p}]@(Partition[p, 2, 1] + Threaded[{1, 0}])

(*{{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 12}, {1, 1, 11}, {14}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 10, 0}}*)
```